# Is there any way in javaScript through that I can open a folder on the client default file explorer

Tags: javascript, browser

Something similar to the "show in finder" of the chrome in mac.
[image: chrome all downloads screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

No, JS has no idea of how the client's file system looks.

Comment: If we provide the exact path to the folder then can we open finder or another default file explorer.

Comment: Actually, I want to provide a way (actually a button)  for the user to open the folder in which he currently downloaded the file.

Comment: No, not possible.